# Why are added tables from Java not visible when I open the H2 console?

Tags: database, h2

I use an H2 embedded database in Java, and after creating the database and adding some tables and data, it gets saved as a file in a directorey of my computer.

But whenever I open this file with the H2 Console, it shows no tables at all? Why are the tables not there?

I am using this URL in my java code: `jdbc:h2:file://C:/Temp/H2/ourDB`

And I log into the console with the following information:

[image: console]

After logging in, I can't see the tables that were created in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have used a different database URL in the H2 Console (not `jdbc:h2:file://C:/Temp/H2/ourDB`). You need to use the same one, otherwise it's a different database.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I actually used the same url but without specifying the database. I used `jdbc:h2:file://C:/Temp/H2` instead of `jdbc:h2:file://C:/Temp/H2/ourDB`.

You solved my problem, thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

The accepted ans is correct- it's URL issue. But for recent user, I am posting the updated values (I am using SpringBoot 2 with Spring Data JPA). When you open H2 Console, the default URL shown for DB Connection is: **jdbc:h2:~/test** . If you connect using this URL, you won't find the tables you created in your app. But user generated tables to be seen use URL as **jdbc:h2:mem:testdb**. Pls, refer below figures:

[image]

[image]

Here EXCHANGE_VALUE was my **JPA generated table**, that i could see after connecting to db using URL as jdbc:h2:mem:testdb.

Comment: used application.properties' "spring.datasource.url" property in spring boot application to get the link to jdbc url