# Problem creating table in H2 database with SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, h2

My greetings for respectful users
I'm newbie with spring boot and i want just create simple table in H2 database 
this is the model class

```
@Entity
public class Human 

{

    @Id
    private long id;


    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

        private String email;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }




        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
}
```

and this is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo-1</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled= true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/user
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

until here the app works well, the only problem that the table doesn't show in H2 console (I don't know if it's really created or not but when I use H2 console the table was created instantly)

So please what's the problem could be?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: you should set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24116962/6572971 might help you

Comment: use this property if you are using in memory database H2 :  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is just adding annotation for main class

```
@EntityScan("com.example.model")
```

So here Spring will scan the package com.example.model and connet with H2 database then create the table

[The table human of origins Human entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EqLd.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of things that you need to check and verify to ensure this works.

- Make sure to define the repository layer correctly.Also ensure you have provided all the correct annotations.
- If you have create queries for the tables make sure that you put these queries in a file name `schema.sql`.Also , ensure that the file is put under the directory `src/main/resources/` folder.But when providing the `schema.sql` **make sure to disable** the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` as **both won't work at the same time** as intented.

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the
>   schema or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.

- If you have any data updation queries to be executed put them inside a file names `data.sql`.Also , ensure that the file is put under the directory `src/main/resources/` folder.This will be executed after the ddl-auto creates the tables.

Repository layer like :

```
@Repository
public interface HumanRepository extends JpaRepository<Human, Integer> {

}
```

As @sovannarith cheav said you need to provide the property in `application.properties` or `application.yml` like :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

The `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property can have different values depending upon your use-case.Values for this property can be :

> validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
>   update: update the schema.
>   create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
>   create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

If this didn't work perhaps springboot is not identifying H2, so try setting the following :

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Official [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization)

Comment: Thank you respectful sir  for the effort done in the answer , I resolved the problem

Comment: @AwadiGhassen If the solution is different from what i have provided, please share it so that others might profit from it as well. Otherwise mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

check the package details you may create entity outside the package